# In Vue.js how do I write custom filters in separate file and use them in various components by declaring in main.js?

Tags: vue.js

I tried doing this, but it does not work.

```js
// filter.js

export default {
    converTimestamp: function (seconds) {
      var date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
      return date.toDateString();
    }
};

// main.js

import customFilters from './store/filters';
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here's an example:

```js
// MyFilter.js
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.filter('myFilter', value => {
  return value.toUpperCase();
});
```

```js
// main.js
import './MyFilter.js';
```

If you don't want to register the filters globally, you can do it like this:

```js
// MyFilter.js
export default function (value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```js
// MyComponent.vue
import MyFilter from './MyFilter.js';

export default {
  filters: {
    MyFilter,
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Decade. It worked !! I registered the filter in the main Vue instance.

Comment: Use [@clem 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51440688/580589) to can reference in components on IDE

Comment: @DecadeMoon in term of performance, what is it the best method?

Comment: @OussamaHe Neither is better or worse performance-wise, it's just a matter of whether you prefer to register the filters globally or import them into each component per-usage (the latter is more work but you can easily trace the source of the filter).

Comment: I think the second method, where import the filter and add it to the filters property is the best. It's more explicit, and you don't have to worry about namespace clashes that way.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have so many filters, you can also define them in a single file:

```js
// filters.js
export default {
    filterA: () => {},
    filterB: () => {},
}
```

And import them globally:

```js
// main.js
import filters from './filters';
for(let name in filters) {
    Vue.filter(name, filters[name]);
}
```

Comment: Actually, a better way to import the filters would be:

`Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => Vue.filter(key, filters[key]))`

It prevents triggering the `guard-for-in` rule from ESLint.

Comment: Here's why it's better to avoid the `for ... in` https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects

Answer (score 2):

For **Vue3**

Create **filters.js** file:

```
const filters = {
    upperCase(value) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
    }
}

export default filters;
```

import the file in **main.js** and use it globally with `globalProperties`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import filters from './filters'
const app = createApp({});
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = filters;
```

Then you can use it directly in template, like that:

```
{{ $filters.upperCase('some text') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a plugin for that:

```js
// filters.js
import Vue from 'vue'

export function truncate( text, length, suffix = '...' ) {
    if (text.length > length) {
        return text.substring(0, length) + suffix;
    } else {
        return text;
    }
}

export function json( value ) {
    return JSON.stringify(value);
}

const filters = { truncate, json }

Object.keys( filters ).forEach( key => {
    Vue.filter( key, filters[ key ] )
})
```

then add this new plugin in the config

```js
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/filters.js']
}
```